# Scheduling Background Service to fetch data in Android

Tags: android, performance, service, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I want to fetch some data from the background in fixed interval of time say 30 minutes. I have implemented the solution using a alarm manager where I call a Service in fixed interval. The process is working fine but the problem I am facing is that it is taking quite few battery power. I want to utilize the battery consumption so that the users don't run away from the application. Alarm is set up like the first part of the code.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, PollingClass.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
am.cancel(pi);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000, 30 * 60 * 1000, pi);
```

In the second part Service class is called by the alarm to execute the task.

```
public class PollingClass extends Service {
     private WakeLock mWakeLock;
     public PollingClass() {
     }

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
          return null;
     }

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "NEW");
    if ((mWakeLock != null) && (mWakeLock.isHeld() == false)) {
        mWakeLock.acquire();
    }
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (!cm.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
        stopSelf();
        return;
    }
    //Calling an Async class to fetch the data from the server
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleIntent(intent);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mWakeLock.release();
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what data are you fecthing?? is from a webservice?

Comment: Yes, Its a JSONArray result returned by NodeJS.

Comment: use volley library it very poweful. and it doesnt consume much battery

Comment: Using volley only for the request and response. The problem I think is with the service or the alarm manager and I am not able to identify what can be done to optimize it.

Comment: DoNT USE Service use IntentSErvice

Comment: Difference between the two?. Is IntentService is better. Implementation is almost the same.

Comment: you dont have to binf your IntentService like you do in your Service. That one of the main difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107684/discussion-between-jarvis-and-jois).

Comment: You know that service runs in main Thread right?? so please using AsyncTask or seperate Thread

Answer (score 0):

IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through `startService(Intent)` calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a **worker thread**, and **stops itself when it runs out of work.** IntentService has a background thread, but only to invoke **onHandleIntent()**. Once **onHandleIntent()** returns, not only does the thread go away, but the service gets destroyed. so this will help your code to run  in different thread when you implement your code in onHandleIntent().

for example:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

         //This is where you will put your volley code or some code that you want to perform in background
}
```

ThankYou. I hope this was helpful.